# Extract the item from the list which has highest number of matches from given String

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist

I have 2 Arraylists in my app. First arraylist is of Object type which contains a list of questions. Now this list of questions have a field named **"Keywords"**. This is a String but can contain comma separated keywords.

Now I have a text field where user can search question based on these keywords.Issue that I am facing is that I want to filter out question from the question list according to the number of keyword matches.

**For eg.** User entered 3 comma separated keywords in the search text field. What I want now is if all 3 keyword matches with some value in the question list then I have to return those elements only. This part is easy and I can do it.

But if we don't get any exact match in the list, then I have to find that item which has the maximum keyword match i.e. if 2 out of 3 keywords from the comma separated String matches from some item in the list, then I have to return that item as result.

**Value Stored in List :-**

```
a) Hi, Hello, Hola, Bonjour.

b) Hi, Hello

c) Hi
```

**Value entered in the search text :-**

```
Hi, Hello, Hola
```

Now in response I want only the first element as it has 3 keywords matching from what user entered.
I am unable to figure out how to do this. Moreover I am fetching this questions list from sqlite database, so if this can be done with some sql queries then I am ready for that thing too.

This is my current code for filter method

```
 public ArrayList<QuestionAnswerModal> filter(String keyword,boolean isQuestionSearch) {
    ArrayList<QuestionAnswerModal> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    if (!isQuestionSearch) {
        for (QuestionAnswerModal modal : questionAnswerArrayList) {
            if (modal.getKeyword().equalsIgnoreCase(keyword)) {
                arrayList.add(modal);
            }else{
                ArrayList<String> keywords=new ArrayList<>();
                String[]word=modal.getKeyword().split(",");

            }
        }
        if (arrayList.size() > 0) {
        System.out.print("list size "+arrayList.size());


        } else {
              System.out.print("No records found");

        }
        return arrayList;
    }else{
        for (QuestionAnswerModal modal : questionAnswerArrayList) {
            if (modal.getQuestion().equalsIgnoreCase(keyword)) {
                arrayList.add(modal);
            }
        }
        if (arrayList.size() > 0) {
          System.out.print("list size "+arrayList.size());


        } else {
            System.out.print("No records found");
        }
        return arrayList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not describe code, show it please.

Comment: I don't know what to code for this. I only have the code for the case of complete match

Comment: Show that. It will give a foundation for proposals.

Comment: @Yunnosch added code

Comment: can you add small example of what you want to achieve

Comment: @aman5319 I have added example as text. Added one more example for more clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many days of trying, I think I found solution to my problem. Below is the code I am using now.

```
public ArrayList<QuestionAnswerModal> filter(String keyword, boolean isQuestionSearch) {
    ArrayList<QuestionAnswerModal> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    HashMap<String, Integer> countList = new HashMap<>();

    if (isQuestionSearch) {
        for (QuestionAnswerModal modal : questionAnswerArrayList) {
            if (modal.getKeyword().equalsIgnoreCase(keyword)) {
                arrayList.add(modal);
            }
        }
        return arrayList;
    } else {
        //will store the index of the question with largest match
        int[] count = new int[questionAnswerArrayList.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < questionAnswerArrayList.size(); i++) {
            List<String> keywords = new ArrayList<>();
            String[] word = questionAnswerArrayList.get(i).getKeyword().split(",");
            keywords = Arrays.asList(word);
            String[] userKeywords = keyword.split(",");
            for (int j = 0; j < userKeywords.length; j++) {
                if (keywords.contains(userKeywords[j])) {
                    if (countList.size() == 0) {
                        //countList.put(userKeywords[j], 1);
                        count[i]++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //index with largest match
        int largest = 0;
        //valu if the index
        int largestCount = count[largest];

        for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
            if (count[i] > largestCount)
                largest = i;
        }

        arrayList.add(questionAnswerArrayList.get(largest));

        if (arrayList.size() > 0) {
            lvQuestionAnswer.invalidate();
            QuestionAnswerAdapter questionAnswerAdapter = new QuestionAnswerAdapter(arrayList, MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this);
            lvQuestionAnswer.setAdapter(questionAnswerAdapter);
            dialog.dismiss();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No records found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return arrayList;


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I leave it to you as an exercise to figure out how this solution works, but feel free to ask any questions you wish.

---

Java 7 solution:

```
import java.util.*;

import static org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.trimToEmpty;

public class MaxMatchFinder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, Set<String>> tagsByName = new HashMap<>();
        tagsByName.put("a", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("Hi", "Hello", "Hola", "Bonjour")));
        tagsByName.put("b", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("Hi", "Hello")));
        tagsByName.put("c", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("Hi")));

        String searchText = "Hi, Hello, Hola";

        String[] tagsToFind = searchText.split(",");

        Map<String, Integer> matchCountsByEntryName = new HashMap<>();

        for (String tagToFind : tagsToFind) {
            for (String entryName : tagsByName.keySet()) {
                Set<String> tags = tagsByName.get(entryName);
                if (tags.contains(trimToEmpty(tagToFind))) {
                    Integer count = matchCountsByEntryName.get(entryName);
                    Integer incrementedCount = count == null ? 1 : count + 1;
                    matchCountsByEntryName.put(entryName, incrementedCount);
                }
            }
        }

        List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> sortedEntries = new ArrayList<>(matchCountsByEntryName.entrySet());
        Collections.sort(sortedEntries, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> e1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> e2) {
                return e2.getValue().compareTo(e1.getValue());
            }
        });

        Map.Entry<String, Integer> entryWithMostMatches = sortedEntries.get(0);

        System.out.printf("Of the entries to be searched," +
            " entry \"%s\" contains the most matches (%d).\n",
                entryWithMostMatches.getKey(), entryWithMostMatches.getValue());
    }
}
```

---

Java 8 solution:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.trimToEmpty;

public class MaxMatchFinder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, Set<String>> tagsByName = new HashMap<>();
        tagsByName.put("a", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("Hi", "Hello", "Hola", "Bonjour")));
        tagsByName.put("b", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("Hi", "Hello")));
        tagsByName.put("c", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("Hi")));

        String searchText = "Hi, Hello, Hola";

        String[] tagsToFind = searchText.split(",");

        Map<String, Integer> matchCountsByEntryName = new HashMap<>();

        Arrays.stream(tagsToFind)
                .forEach(tagToFind -> {
                    for (String entryName : tagsByName.keySet()) {
                        Set<String> tags = tagsByName.get(entryName);
                        if (tags.contains(trimToEmpty(tagToFind))) {
                            matchCountsByEntryName.compute(entryName, (k, v) -> v == null ? 1 : v + 1);
                        }
                    }
                });

        List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> sortedEntries = matchCountsByEntryName.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted((e1, e2) -> e2.getValue().compareTo(e1.getValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        Map.Entry<String, Integer> entryWithMostMatches = sortedEntries.get(0);

        System.out.printf("Of the entries to be searched," +
            " entry \"%s\" contains the most matches (%d).\n",
                entryWithMostMatches.getKey(), entryWithMostMatches.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a solution without using Java8. Myy app is currently build using Java 7

Comment: I added to the Java 7 solution to the existing solution for Java 8. Better now?

Comment: Those a,b,c are not keys. I just used them to show 3 options. It was just for numbering.

Comment: Also what you have shown in the code seems like to find which keywords has the most count, but question is not limited to that.I have to find which index objects in the object arraylist has the most matching keywords

Comment: Can you please change your code example to something that takes out all of the Android-dependent classes such as Toast, QuestionAnswerModal, etc and just encapsulate your algorithm in simple data structures that I can easily copy/paste into my IDE? I think that may allow us to make better progress if you'd be willing to make that change for me.

Comment: I would do that for sure

Comment: Removed all android dependencies

Comment: I would consider QuestionAnswerModal to be an Android dependency as well. Can you please show only collections of strings? (ie - List<String> as opposed to ArrayList<QuestionAnswerModal>.

Comment: This is not android dependency. This is just an arraylist of object type. I won't be able to accomplish my requirements with simple string type. Question answer modal is a getter setter class

Comment: Very well, but I looked over your requirements again and my solution seems to give you exactly what you want. It returns the list of keywords with the maximum number of matches as you stated. Not sure what else I can do.

Comment: Then it seems you didn't get the complete question. What I want is to get the question from the question answer list which has the most key words matches.

Comment: Getting the most matching keywords is only one part of the question